# Can't get full text on on_status method in Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I can't get the full text of statuses.
I tried "status.full_text" and some similar things, but *status* has no such attributes.

On the contrary,

```
tweets = api.search(q='athens', tweet_mode='extended')
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.full_text)
```

this worked just fine. It seems like *tweet* has "full_text" attribute but *status* not.

So what do I have to change in the code below to get the full text of the status?

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

my_stream_listener = MyStreamListener()
my_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener, tweet_mode='extended')

my_stream.filter(track=['Athens'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `status.extended_tweet["full_text"]`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/935#issuecomment-373202908).